# Silex global form validation

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, symfony-forms, silex

I would like to add a global validator for my form. Its goal would be to check the Google captcha that I include on my form (but not as a form element).

I would also be used to check the global consistency of the data submitted. e.g. If the first element has been filled, the second become required.

So far I created a RecaptchaService with an isValid() method.

I also tried to add the following code in my form. It works but it adds the validator on all my fields instead of globally on the form.

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $validator = $this->app['service.captcha'];

    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'validation_groups' => function(FormInterface $form) use ($validator) {
            $validator->isValid($form);
        }
    ));
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: The only way I found so far is to add more logic in my controller after the ```if (form->isValid())```
Any way to do it another way?